# Add a suffix to numbers on axis ticks?

Tags: r, ggplot2

`number` makes it easy to append a suffix to a number for labeling. Is there a way to do this for ticks on an axis?

For example, in the screenshot below, I'd like to append `M` to the axis ticks.

My code looks like this right now:
 `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, n.breaks = 3, expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)))` Is there something I could pass in for the `labels` value?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scales::dollar` has `suffix` option. So something like this should work.

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) scales::dollar(x, suffix = 'M'), 
                   n.breaks = 3, expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)))
```